# Collections in XML, the right structure

Tags: xml

I'm wondering what is the difference between two below XML structure when we have collection. Which one is preferred?

```
-- having <Databases> node and list the databases inside it
<Server>
    <Databases>
        <Database Name="master"/>
        <Database Name="temp"/>
        <Database Name="pubs"/>
    </Databases>
</Server>

-- No using <Databases> node, list databases directly under <Server> node
<Server>
    <Database Name="master"/>
    <Database Name="temp"/>
    <Database Name="pubs"/>
</Server>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first one is better if that is the only info needed, but the second one can hold more info under the server like a user node

Comment: If I want to add User to the first structure, I will add a <Users> node first and then list <User> nodes underneath. So I think there is no limitation in each of them. I agree that the second one consume less storage and is simpler than the firs one but I don't have a good reason to use the second one.

Comment: I did mean the second one and Your use of a users node would be very good xml